# Qt C++ using constraints in function templates

Tags: c++, qt, templates, constraints, keyword

Using Qt I tried to declare function template for calculate some values only for `quint8`, `quint16` and `quint32`.
I wrote:

```
template<typename T>
concept CrcCompatible = typeid(T) == typeid(quint8) || typeid(T) == typeid(quint16) || typeid(T) == typeid(quint32);

template<typename T> requires CrcCompatible<T>
T crc(T initial, T polynomial, T *pcBlock, T len, bool isFinalXor);
```

But`concept` and `requires` keywords doesn't highlighted as part of the syntax. When I try compile this code folowing errors occured:

```
concept does not name a type
...
requires does not name a type
```

I try use templates in Qt very first time. I doesn't understand how to fix this error, and why compiler can't understand keywords.

In project file I add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` and `CONFIG += c++11`
but nothing changed.

I can't understand what I should ask in google, so I couldn't find answer...

Comment: Off topic: it is Qt, not QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that concepts are not supported in C++11. From what I can see in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), the concepts will only be [available in C++20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/concept). Anyway, if the are supported by some compiller right now you should enable this support by some other flag than `--std=c++11`.

Comment: I was really careless